# Make effective the changes in CPU governor plugin

Tags: debian, xfce, cpu

I'm using Debian Testing + Xfce. I added to my panel the plugin the handle the CPU governor.

My problem is that the setting that I do on the plugin interface are not made effective. Maybe because I'm not running it as root? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Have a look at this message (from the developer?) in a bug report](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7372#c4), showing you that *everything works as it is supposed to*

> This is a very counter intuitive behavior of this application, that needs to be fixed eventually:
>
> Despite what it looks like, cpufreq does not currently allow you to change the governor. It merely lists the available ones, and highlight the current one. **Unfortunately, it does so in a way that makes it look like you could change them.**
>
> I'll try to fix this whenever I have time, which might not be immediately.

Maybe you'll be lucky with XFCE 4.10; although [the bug reports would probably have been closed then](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-cpufreq-plugin)

([Here's the source, btw, you could help out with this feature](https://github.com/frivoal/xfce4-cpugraph-plugin))